# How to set textbox width fit in table cell CSS

Tags: html, css, webgrid

i am working with mvc webgrid which render table at run time. i want my text box width will be same as table cell width. each table cell has some with and when i set textbox `width=100%` then UI getting messed up. 
i use the below css

```
.edit-mode {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
}
```

so i am looking for help regarding css. here is the image of my grid.
[image]

here is jsfiddle link where anyone can see my css and html code. https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/qvy0y8sk/

looking for guidance for css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these to your input style:

```
display: inline;
width: 100%;
height: 100%
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
border: none;  /* if you want no box around the input field */
```

likewise in the td style of those inputs remove the padding spec

Comment: sorry no luck. i applied your css but got the same UI. i want my textbox height and width will be same as table cell height width.

Comment: I did it in your fiddle, but only tried the width... not sure about the height

Answer (score 1):

If i understood right, you need [box-sizing](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#propdef-box-sizing) to apply a correct width: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvy0y8sk/1/)

```
td input, td button {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: beat me by 28 seconds!

Comment: sorry no luck. i applied your css but got the same UI. i want my textbox height and width will be same as table cell height width.

Comment: @Mou ah, did not notice for the height ... PLEASE, update your question for the height issue as well . IMHO, strange to look for streching an imput as it would be a textarea. You may look for the attribute  contenteditable="true" applied to the cell itself, so the whole cell is an edit area